# Dockerfile for .sqlite3 database

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, dockerfile, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I currently have a Django application I want to deploy. The database being used is SQLite3 and I would like to run it in a separate container as the web application. I need to create a docker image of the Database and push it to my repo on AWS ECR. I already have an image of the application there but need a seperate image of the database so the data will persist. Any advice on creating a DockerFile or docker-compose file to do this would be great.

Comment: SQLite is an embedded database that doesn't use a server. There wouldn't be much point to putting a SQLite db in another container. What you should do is create a volume for your app container and copy it there. This is outside the scope of the question but I would suggest, as you're using AWS, to use AWS RDS for your database.

Comment: Thank you, this is the approach I am now taking!!

Comment: No problem. Good luck with yourproject.